# C: Loop pops out even when condition is still satisfied

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

this is a demo of linklist written in C.

Description: The code is about manipulating the linkist like insert, delete, display the linked list.

problem:

1. I choose 1 to insert value to node (ex: 1) then value; 2,3,4...
2. Then I delete the head element the code exit. It's supposed to continue running as the condition of the loop is still satisfied.

same problem if you intend to display the linked list.

```
// ==============================
// Linked List Demo
// ==============================
// 1. Insert to head
// 2. Delete elements by value
// 3. Display all elements
// 4. Search an element
// 5. Delete an element by position
// 6. Exit
// ==============================
// Your choice:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node intLinkedList;

int insertToHead();
void display(intLinkedList *head);
void displayForLoop(intLinkedList *head);
int deleteFromHead(intLinkedList **head);
int delete(int value, intLinkedList **head);
int indexOf(int value, intLinkedList *head);

void menu();
void menu(){
    char* mainMenu[] = {"Insert to head", "Delete", "Display", \
                         "Search Element", "Delete by position", "Exit"};
    printf("=====================================\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s \n", i + 1,  mainMenu[i]);
    }
    printf("=====================================\n");
}
int main(){
    int choice;
    int value;
    intLinkedList *head;

    do{
        menu();
        printf("#Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("--> %d", choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("Input new Value to Linked List: ");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                insertToHead(value, &head);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Input new Value to delete : ");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                if(delete(value, &head)){
                    printf("%d removed from linked list \n", value);
                }else{
                    printf(" %d not in linked  list \n", value);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Display all elements \n");
                display(head);
                break;
            case 4: 
                printf("Input value to search: ");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                int found = indexOf(value, head);
                if( found < 0){
                    printf("%d is isn't in linked list ", value);
                }else{
                    printf("%d is in linked list at %d positino \n", value, found);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Delete by position : ");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("EXIT..");
                return 0;

            default:
                printf(": \n");
                break;
        } 
    }while(choice != 6);  
}

int insertToHead(int value, intLinkedList **head){
    intLinkedList *newElement;
    newElement = (intLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(intLinkedList));
    newElement -> value = value;
    newElement -> next = *head;
    *head = newElement;
    return 1;
}


void displayForLoop(intLinkedList *head){
    intLinkedList *iterator;
    for(iterator=head; iterator!=NULL; iterator=iterator->next){
        printf("|value: %d| ->", iterator->value);
    }
    printf(" NULL\n");
}

void display(intLinkedList *head){
    intLinkedList *iterator;
    iterator = head;
    while( iterator != NULL){
        printf("|value : %d| -> ", iterator -> value);
        iterator = iterator -> next;
    }
    printf("NULL \n");
}
int deleteFromHead(intLinkedList **head){
    if( *head == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    intLinkedList *del;
    del = *head;
    *head = del -> next;
    free(del);
    return 1;
}
int delete(int value, intLinkedList **head){
    intLinkedList *current;
    intLinkedList *pre;
    current = *head;
    pre = *head;
    int deleted = 0;

    if(current->value == value){
        printf("get here\n");
        deleteFromHead(head);
        return 1;
    }

    while(current != NULL){
        if(current->value == value){
            deleted = 1;
            if(current==*head){
                deleteFromHead(head);
                current = *head;
                pre = *head;
            }else{
                pre->next = current->next;
                free(current);
                current = pre->next;
            }
            continue;
        }
        pre = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return deleted;
}

int indexOf(int value, intLinkedList *head){
    intLinkedList *iterator;
    int i;
    for( iterator = head, i = 0; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator -> next, i++){
        if(iterator -> value = value){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: [mcve] is needed.

Comment: Start by stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: THIS is a "complete", "verifiable example", what do you mean?

Comment: @VeronykaMunteanu it's definitely complete and verifiable, but it's not minimal. If you can trim the amount of code down to just what produces the bug then it's much easier for others to read and will quite possibly lead you to discover the exact bug yourself.

Comment: for instance, with code requiring user interactive input, bugs cannot be reproduced easily.

Comment: Please prove that the loop is left in spite of still valid condition. I.e. print the checked variable just before the loop condition is checked and print just after the loop is left. Show the output. Also, making your complete and verifiable example minimal (i.e. it only consists of the loop and the update of the value) will make you find the error yourself.

Comment: To: McLemore, Jean-Francois Fabre and Yunnosch: Thanks a lot. Even dbush gave a very general but good comment.

To the guy who just passed the link + two words "is needed". Why bother commenting while you just look at my code and don't bother reading it?
------
I sincerely thanks Stackoverflow community because every time I have problem you guys have answer, but people like Eugene Sh is really just trying to get points or ranks without really helping the community.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking undefined behavior by not initializing `head`. Consider the first time you insert an element, you call `insertToHead` .. then you execute `newElement -> next = *head;`.  `head` was not initialized, so `*head` is garbage, and your first element `->next` value is "initialized" to some indeterminate value.  Your `displayForLoop` function, for instance, keeps looping until `->next` is NULL.  This may not be the only problem but it is certainly a problem.  Whenever you traverse your linked-list looking for `->next == NULL` as the marker for the end of the list, this is going to cause problems.  Initialize `head` with `intLinkedList *head = NULL;` to fix this problem.

Comment: @VeronykaMunteanu no worries hope you get it working!